# AutoCompletition textField

Tags: java, textfield

Im using an Autosuggerstor textField posted on stackoverflow at [Create a autocompleting textbox in Java with a dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186955/create-a-autocompleting-textbox-in-java-with-a-dropdown-list/14194104#14194104)

This really nice component allow you to select from a list of matching words in a dictionary to write faster and with correct sintax (a sort of intellisense)

I was trying to add the feature of automatic autocompletition when a typed word has only one match and spacebar is hitten.

The following should do the trick

```
private void checkForAndShowSuggestions() {
    String text=textField.getText();

    boolean hitSpace=false;

    if (text.contains(" "))
        hitSpace =  text.lastIndexOf(" ")==text.length()-1;
    if(labelz.size()==1&&hitSpace){
        labelz.get(0).replaceWithSuggestedText();
        return;
    }
```

where labelz contains the last list of suggestions.

but i get the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(AbstractDocument.java:1338)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:658)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1669)
    at ygg.desktop.vm.components.SuggestionLabel.replaceWithSuggestedText(SuggestionLabel.java:89)
    at ygg.desktop.vm.components.AutoSuggestor.checkForAndShowSuggestions(AutoSuggestor.java:183)
    at ygg.desktop.vm.components.AutoSuggestor.access$0(AutoSuggestor.java:174)
    at ygg.desktop.vm.components.AutoSuggestor$1.insertUpdate(AutoSuggestor.java:44)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:669)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.replaceSelection(JTextComponent.java:1328)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$DefaultKeyTypedAction.actionPerformed(DefaultEditorKit.java:884)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6310)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Apparently i cant change the textfield inside this thread, is there any way around it? like adding the labelz.get(0).replaceWithSuggestedText(); code to some sort of queue?

here is where the exception generates in my source

```
void replaceWithSuggestedText() {
    String suggestedWord = getText(); 
    String text = textField.getText(); 
    String typedWord = autoSuggestor.getCurrentlyTypedWord(); 
    String t = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(typedWord)); 
    String tmp = t + text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(typedWord)).replace(typedWor‌​d, suggestedWord); 
    textField.setText(tmp + " ");//exception line
    }
```

Comment: The error occurs in `replaceWithSuggestedText`, please provide its code or better yet, a [mcve] .

Comment: void replaceWithSuggestedText() {
        String suggestedWord = getText();
        String text = textField.getText();
        String typedWord = autoSuggestor.getCurrentlyTypedWord();
        String t = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(typedWord));
        String tmp = t + text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(typedWord)).replace(typedWord, suggestedWord);
        textField.setText(tmp + " ");//exception line
    }

Comment: how do i edit? the full code is reported in the link at the top, i only added the lines i posted

Comment: Your error stack shows that you are using a `DocumentListener`, check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788779/java-lang-illegalstateexception-while-using-document-listener-in-textarea-java and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206586/getting-attempt-to-mutate-notification-exception

Comment: thank you! SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable) did the trick, now im getting ifinite autocompletes XD but this i can figure out

Comment: Have a look at the second answer from the first link, it explains how to deal with that.

Comment: thanks, i added a boolean to the label and i use it now in the line if(labelz.size()==1&&hitSpace&&!labelz.get(0).justAutoCompleted) and did some changes here and there to get the correct amount of spaces.now it works fine for the most... will look into that tomorrow.