# [IllegalStateException : Attempt to Mutate in Notification]

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jbutton, documentlistener

I want to make a `documentListener` that *if I type in the `JTextField : txt_ip4class` and match regex of IPv4 format* it will change the `JComboBox : box_ip4class` content.

If the content is changed (`itemStateChanged`), range of IP Class will be written down to `JTextField : txt_rangeclass`, *and* bit usage will be write down to `JTextField : txt_bitclass``*.

I have succeeded in this method, but with a classic method *(using `jButton`)*, but I failed in this method using `documentListener`. Only `JComboBox : box_ip4Class` changed.

My code, applying `documentListener` to `txt_ip4class`:

```
txt_ip4class.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        logUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        logUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        logUpdate();
    }

    void logUpdate() {
        Runnable doHighlight = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String aTxt = txt_ip4class.getText();
                    classValue = 1;
                    if (!aTxt.matches("\\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\\.|$)){4}\\b")) {
                        classValue = 0;
                    } else if (aTxt.matches("\\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\\.|$)){4}\\b")) {
                        try {
                            classW.classMain(classValue, box_ip4class, txt_ip4class, txt_rangeclass, txt_bitclass);

                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doHighlight);
        }
});
```

`classW.Main` contains two conditions, if zero it will set other fields based on `jComboBox` (`txt_ip4class` will be replaced), if one it should be set `jComboBox` choosing an option. And from that option, it should do like option zero

Full code (I export these files from Netbeans project *to zip*):

1. [Succeed method which using jButton to execute](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GLdIdzmZCB6DZXg_ga5t34gRLQO1Lj6X/view?usp=sharing)
2. [Failed method which using documentListener without jButton](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FGaORt9mq9NdjPTV7DG2OtOxxiPULuuv/view?usp=sharing)

Full exception stacktrace is [here](https://pastebin.com/0s90ddre)

or

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(AbstractDocument.java:1338)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:658)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1669)
    at engines.ClassW.setFromCombo(ClassW.java:140)
    at interfaces.Netgui$1.logUpdate(Netgui.java:63)
    at interfaces.Netgui$1.insertUpdate(Netgui.java:41)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:669)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.replaceSelection(JTextComponent.java:1328)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$DefaultKeyTypedAction.actionPerformed(DefaultEditorKit.java:884)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6310)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 19 seconds)
```

===============EDIT 1============

Thanks to @MarkRotteveel
And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115180/illegalstateexception-attempt-to-mutate-in-notification)

This problem is fixed, but another problem is exist..
Code in the `doHighlight` is running in a loop.

===============EDIT 2============

Updated the code. 
doHighlight no longer looping when the condition doesn't equal the regex.
but still doing loop when the condition equals.

Comment: Please post the full exception stracktrace.

Comment: Added @MarkRotteveel

Comment: You're trying to modify the document from an event triggered by modification of a document. That is not allowed. Maybe you should instead queue the modification (eg using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`). Note, my swing is rusty, so I might be wrong here.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206586/getting-attempt-to-mutate-notification-exception

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel, that problem is fixed, but another problem come lol, while I wait the other answer, I will try to fix this too